# How to change the color of UISegmentedControl? My tint doesn't display

Tags: ios, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to have a simple `UISegmentedControl` with a `tint`. In the `xcode interface`, I chose the following parameters:

```
- Style = bar
 - Tint = red
 - Image = blank
```

When viewed on `storyboard`, I see a nice segmented control with a dark red drop shadow, but on my phone I just see a nearly white control bar when I don't have any `UIImage` arranged behind the segmented control. If I place a blank `UIImage` with a black background behind the segmented control, the segmented control appears a nice dark grey with a black drop shadow and white letters, but no red is seen.

Does anyone know how to see the red tint that is present in `storyboard` on my actual phone?

Comment: Please post the code you are using so we can offer some help.

Comment: I didn't code in any appearance modifications, I just used the interface builder for that. So, my code would just show you which segment is selected for a given method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I change the tint color for a `UISegmentedControl`:

```
UISegmentedControl  *seg        = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item1", @"item2", @"item3", nil]];
seg.tag                         = 1;
seg.segmentedControlStyle       = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
seg.frame                       = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
[seg addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
seg.tintColor                   = [UIColor redColor];
seg.selectedSegmentIndex        = 0
[yourContainerView addSubview:seg];
```

This should also do the trick for you!

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back!